# Some time in mozilla firefox 42.0 ng-model variable is undefined even though this have value in text-area field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, textangular

Some time in mozilla firefox 42.0 i am getting undefined ng-model variable but when i have upgraded 43.0 its working fine. Is any buddy faces the same problem and found any solution.

Example: html file contain code like this

```
<div text-angular="" name="indiCont" ng-model="vm.chapter.content.procedureDetails.indiCont" class="cb-edit-txtarea"></div>
```

some time i am getting error **vm.chapter.content.procedureDetails.indiCont is undefined even though it has text in html editor**

Comment: Where does vm.chapter.content.procedureDetails come from?

Comment: It is so specific, maybe you should better make a jsfiddle for it. 

Generally speaking, the two-way data binding in angularjs is based on the 'digest' procedure. When the model variable and the DOM do not match, it might be caused that a digestion procedure has NOT got chance to run yet.

Comment: @Nora **vm.chapter.content** variable is declared in controller.

Comment: Does its value come from a promise? Can you show code, set up jsfiddle?